# CSS - Dynamic size Div - full width responsive background

Tags: html, css

I have a full page DIV which has a slide in section (similar to the Facebook App) as seen in the partially built page in teh screenshot below -

[image]

I need to apply a background image to the main column that stretches to full width and remains in place as the page scrolls over it -  as per a standard statically positioned cover image - but I also need it to move with the container when the slide in section is activated, which goes against a staic images property's - and is giving me a headache± -  Anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

**Update**
This is basically the template I'm working off for the site - http://jsbin.com/AviNUxA/2/edit.
So I need a background image applying to the main panel - which will remain statically positioned - but also move when the window slides to the right..
    http://jsbin.com/AviNUxA/2/edit

Comment: Can you share the link to some website which better shows what you need( may be facebook url)

Comment: if possible come up with some demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Is this what you want : https://www.facebook.com/policies/?ref=pf

Comment: Hi chaps - added a link above which hopefully better explains what I'm working with!  Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

find this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
```

insert this after.... and use css provided...

```
<div id="background">
        <img src="yourimageurl.jpg" class="stretch">
      </div>
```

css

```
#background{
z-index:-90;
position:absolute;
}
.stretch{
width:100%;
height:100%;}
```

you can stretch the image as needed.

Hope this is what you are looking for..

something like this  http://jsbin.com/EbEZOZIl/1/edit